# htaccess send content after ? as a parameter

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

This is my input URL

http://site_name/project/edit/sgdsg/getFile/?file=271bbec45d7855a332e6dfda85ca94b9.txt

I want it to be sent like 
http://site_name/project/edit/sgdsg/getFile/271bbec45d7855a332e6dfda85ca94b9.txt

How can we do this? I want this only for the URL starting with http://site_name/project/edit/sgdsg/getFile/
So it don't affect any other URL.

This is what I have tried ...

```
RewriteRule ^project/edit/([A-Za-z0-9._-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9._-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9._-]+)/?$ modules-nct/edit_project-nct/index.php?slug=$1&action=method&method=$2&file=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^project/edit/([A-Za-z0-9._-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9._-]+)/?$ modules-nct/edit_project-nct/index.php?slug=$1&action=method&method=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^project/edit/([A-Za-z0-9._-]+)/?$ modules-nct/edit_project-nct/index.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

Please don't give it negative ratings just because my editing is improper.I am here to learn something new.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your `<a>` tag:

```
<a href="your_url/your_other_parameters(means :project/edit/sgdsg/getFile/ )/directly enter your file name that you want to pass"> i.e your <a> tag must be

<a href="http://site_name/project/edit/sgdsg/getFile/271bbec45d7855a332e6dfda85ca94b9.txt"></a>
```

In htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^project/edit/([A-Za-z0-9._-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9._-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9._-]+)$ modules-nct/edit_project-nct/index.php?slug=$1&action=method&method=$2&file=$3
```

In the above line, the `href` URL will be redirected to an original URL.

Comment: The point is not about how should I call url but how to handle it... However thanks mate..